# Camera Functionality Not displaying Image

Tags: javascript, android, html, camera

I have a hybrid application, which opens native camera of android.
My code :

```
public class CameraFunActivity extends Activity {  
    OpenCamera openCamera;  

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
       setContentView(R.layout.main);    
     WebView webView=(WebView)findView  ById(R.id.webkitWebView1);  
     WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();  
     settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
     settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true); 
      openCamera=new OpenCamera(webView,CameraFunActivity.this);  
         webView.addJavascriptInterface(openCamera,"camera");

    }  
   @Override   
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

     if (requestCode== 0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){ 
         System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Camera Working...........");
         String imagePath =  "file:/"+openCamera.getPath();
        System.out.println("Image Pathhhhhhhhhh :::::::::::: " + imagePath);
        openCamera.setPath(imagePath);
```

..
}

HTML:
    
    function captureImage1(){
     camera.startCamera();
     var path="file://" + camera.getPath();
     //alert(path);
     document.getElementById("image1").src=path;
    }

public OpenCamera (WebView appView,Activity context) {
        this.mAppView = appView;
        this.context=context;
    }

```
public void setPath(String path){

    _path=path;
}
public String getPath(){

    return _path;
}
public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
    System.out.println("setting bitmap");
    this.bitmap=bitmap;
}
public Bitmap getBitmap(){
    System.out.println("getting bitmap");
    return bitmap;
}

public void startCamera(){
    /*
    Camera camera = Camera.open();
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);*/

    Date dt = new Date();   
    int date=dt.getDate();
    int hours = dt.getHours();   
    int minutes = dt.getMinutes(); 
    int seconds = dt.getSeconds();   
    String curTime = date+"_"+hours + "_"+minutes + "_"+ seconds;
    _path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/"+curTime+".jpg";
    File file = new File( _path );
    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file );
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
    intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );





//  System.out.println("Paramssssssssssssss  " + camera.getParameters().toString());

    context.startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

Sometimes it dispalays the image at img tag src, sometimes it doesn't. Need help to find out the problem.

Also, is it something related to Orientation change??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it in this way :

add :
    function openCamera1(){
          result = camera.startCameraActivity1();
          path1=camera.getImagePath1();
          path="file://"+path1;
          do{
                     fileIndicator=camera.findEOF();
                 }while(!fileIndicator)
                    document.getElementById("image1").src=path;
           }

And in OpenCamera add a method:

```
public boolean findEOF(){  
       File file=new File(imagePath1);  
       System.out.println("Inisde EOFL::::::::::::::"+file.length());  

        if(file.length()>0){ 
           System.out.println("Inisde length is::::::::::::::"+file.length());  
            return true;
      }         
       return false;

   }
```

So the problem was get imagePath() was being called before the image is written to the file